# How to insert the ng-template into dynamically added external element in Angular.?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following ng template in html file

```
<ng-template #myradio>
        <p-radioButton name="test" value="server1" [(ngModel)]="type"></p-radioButton>
        <p-radioButton name="test" value="server2" [(ngModel)]="type"></p-radioButton>
        <label class="server">Select the server
</ng-template>
```

And on page load another one external component will be loaded, onclick of the external component button, dialog will be loaded on the screen. And I want to insert above ng-template inside the dialog box

So, to attach the custom onclick and insert the viewchild I have added the following code,

```
export TestClass implements AfterViewInit{
    @ViewChild('myradio') myradio;
    typer= "server1";


    ngAfterViewInit(){
      document.querySelector('#external-div-element').addEventListener('click', () => {
              console.log("attached click");
              setTimeout(() => {
                      document.querySelectorAll('#external-div-element .p-grid')[2].appendChild(myradio);
              }, 500);
      });
    }
}
```

but the appendchild is not adding the element to the external dialog.

Comment: You can do it [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-abnmtt)

Comment: And if you want to pass a template to another component, you can do [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kd2bp9)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example that appends a template's content to another element (simulating the dialog) in the same page. You can adjust the code to do the same inside your dialog:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <ng-template #myTemplate>
      <div>This content is appended programmatically</div>
    </ng-template>
    <div #myDialog>
      <p>initial dialog content</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <button id="myButton" (click)="onClick()">Append content</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('myTemplate', { read: TemplateRef }) myTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('myDialog', { read: ViewContainerRef }) myDialog!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor() {}

  onClick(): void {
    const view = this.myTemplate.createEmbeddedView(null);

    (this.myDialog.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement).appendChild(view.rootNodes[0]);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[See here the working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/append-ng-template-content)